# Is it possible to retrieve only doc id and score from Elasticsearch without performing the fetch phase of search?

Tags: elasticsearch

[Understanding "Query Then Fetch"](https://www.elastic.co/blog/understanding-query-then-fetch-vs-dfs-query-then-fetch) shows that an Elasticsearch query is a two step process of query (find/score/sort matching documents from all servers) and fetching (go back to the servers and collect the content of the matching documents).

Is there a way to retrieve only a list of sorted doc_id and score but avoid the fetch? I know that fetch can be avoided by setting size to 0... but I still need the matching docs and their scores and that would return none.

I figure I *might* be able to turn off _source, but I'm not sure that would work if, for example, the query portion of the search only knows the internal doc_id and needs to go and retrieve the public doc_id.

Answer (score 0):

GET /_search
{
"_source": false,
"query" : {
"term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
}
}

off course, you have to use your own ids, not auto-generated ones

Answer (score 0):

The scores are separated from the docs' sources so I don't see why a fetch would be necessary to retrieve them.

---

You can surely turn off `_source` and then also sort by `_id`, like so:

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "_source": false, 
  "size": 200, 
  "sort": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Interestingly enough, sorting the response by doc's `_source` field seems to be ~3x faster than sorting by the inner `_id` (Contrary to what I expected). I've tested this w/ quite a small index -- ~1.5M docs. I wonder what you get when you run

```
GET your_index/_search?request_cache=false
{
  "_source": false, 
  "size": 200, 
  "sort": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and then replace `_id` with another doc's `_source` sortable field.

Comment: disable _source should help.

Sorting on high cardinality fields and _id especially should be avoided as it may cause memory issues especially [before 7.6](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/49166). Assuming the shards are not forced merge to one segment file, the global ordinal map in memory will be huge (`GET _cat/fielddata`)
Keyword is datatype to use for aggregation and sorting on _id should be avoided, but per question I think score is wanted hence sorting by _id is also not needed

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. Really helpful info.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed by setting size to `0`, we will be skipping the fetch phase. In all other cases, if have even a single hit, the fetch phase will be executed and there is no way to skip it.

As you correctly noted, the query phase doesn't know the real _ids of matched documents, only their internal doc ids on respected shard. As a part of the fetch phase we will retrieve those _ids, which are stored as a stored field in Lucene. _source is a separate stored field from _id, which is also loaded during the fetch phase.  But to speed the fetch phase, you can disable loading _source if you don't need it. Being a separate field from _id, disabling _source doesn't affect the correct loading of _ids.